# Merging multiple similar product into one product and show sum of the merged products in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

[The dataframe looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GG2yx.png)

Hello I just started today with Pandas.

I have been trying to find an answer for my problem, but I can't really find any solution.

I am trying to analyze the sales data in my bubble tea shop.

For example product: Mango is substring of Mangon

so they should be merged to only one product. I managed to mispell when i inserted this product in the cashier system, but they are the same product..

I have a dataframe called df with 123 rows x 3 columns.

Example:

```
product_name      product_sold              product_revenue

04.Thaai Tea                10                         650

06.Thaien Tea               25                        1625

08.Maango Tea               40                        2600

09.MangoIs Tea               5                         325

10.MangoKre Tea              5                         325
```

Expected output to new df:

```
product_name      product_sold              product_revenue

Thai Tea                    35                         2275

Mango Tea                   50                         3250
```

So multiple products with quite similar names should be just one product in the new dataframe and it should be able to see the result of product_revenue in new df.

Comment: To create a reliable script for any sort of analysis, I think you need to create some sort of map between `product_name` and your desired `product_category`.

Answer (score 3):

I propose an approach a little different from those they have proposed until now, but I think that for your problem it is the best solution. The solution I propose is based on **[NLP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing)** (Natural Language Processing).

Given your dataset input and a list of `categories`, I calculate the distance between the words using **[word2vec](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word2vec)** and **[cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity)**. In this way even words with grammatical errors will be similar to the correct word (mango ~ mnagos, thaai ~ thaaien). 
I then create a new column `extracted_category` formed extracted from the `product_name` and I do group_by up on the column `extracted_category`.

Below is the complete code:

```
import pandas as pd

categories = ["Mango", "Thai", "Green", "Black", "Brown", "Caramel", "Milk", "Coconut", "Coffee", "Cocos"]

def word2vec(word):
    from collections import Counter
    from math import sqrt

    # count the characters in word
    cw = Counter(word)
    # precomputes a set of the different characters
    sw = set(cw)
    # precomputes the "length" of the word vector
    lw = sqrt(sum(c*c for c in cw.values()))

    # return a tuple
    return cw, sw, lw

def cosdis(v1, v2):
    # which characters are common to the two words?
    common = v1[1].intersection(v2[1])
    # by definition of cosine distance we have
    return sum(v1[0][ch]*v2[0][ch] for ch in common)/v1[2]/v2[2]

def nearest_categories(word):
    d_sim = {category: cosdis(word2vec(word),word2vec(category)) for category in categories}
    return sorted(d_sim.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

def extract_categories(descr):
    word = descr.split('.')[1].split(' ')[0]
    nearest_category = nearest_categories(word)[0]
    return nearest_category

####### ----------------------------------------- #######

raw_data = {'product_name':    ['04.Thaai Tea', '06.Thaien Tea', 
                               '08.Maango Tea', '09.MangoIs Tea', 
                               '10.MangoKre Tea'],
        'product_sold':    [10, 25, 40, 5, 5],
        'product_revenue': [650, 1625, 2600, 325, 325]}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)
df['extracted_category'] = df['product_name'].apply(lambda name: extract_categories(name)[0])

df.groupby(df["extracted_category"]).sum()
```

Result:

```
                    product_sold  product_revenue
extracted_category                               
Mango                         50             3250
Thai                          35             2275
```

Comment: @Massifox that is a awesome solution. Do you have any python related links to that also use a similar approach?

Comment: Specifically the `cosdis` step. How do I run that on it's own, what are the two inputs, two vectors?

Comment: @JohnFriel I'm glad you enjoyed my solution.  It's a bit complicated to be able to explain here in the comments, I try.  Maybe I'll update the answer later by delving into the part you asked for.

Comment: cosine similarity is a mathematical function that allows us to calculate the distance between two numerical vectors.  It is used in NLP to calculate the similarity between words (more generated between documents).  Ok, but the documents are composed of text, not numbers ... the first step is to transform each document into a numerical vector.  To do this there are many methods (including word2vec that I used in the example, but maybe it's not the most intuitive to start with).

Comment: A simple method to transform a document into a numerical vector is to exploit a Boolean model: given to the common vocabulary, each 1 represents the presence of the word of the vocabulary in the document, or the absence.  For example: given the vocabulary: ['dog', 'cat', 'pizza'] and two documents d1 = ["my dog ​​eat pizza"], d2 = ["the cat is on the table"] will be represented according to this  simple model as two boolen vectors: v1 = [1,0,1], v2 = [0,0,1].  v1 represents that d1 contains the words dog and pizza, while v2 contains the word cat.

Comment: At this point it is possible to calculate the cosine distance or any other mathematical function on the two vectors.  obviously this was just an example to let you quickly understand how the game works :)

Comment: let me know if I'm clear enough and if you liked the explanation @JohnFriel

Answer (score 0):

try this

```py
df.groupby(df["product_name"].str.split(".").str[-1]).sum()
```

it will split the string at "." and take the last part

Comment: You can use str.replace method with regex to remove the prefix

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this in one fell swoop. I think you need to create a lookup.

If this is your current dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
raw_data = {'product_name':    ['04.Thaai Tea', '06.Thaien Tea', 
                               '08.Maango Tea', '09.MangoIs Tea', 
                               '10.MangoKre Tea'],
        'product_sold':    [10, 25, 40, 5, 5],
        'product_revenue': [650, 1625, 2600, 325, 325]}

tea_data = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)
```

I think you need to make a lookup like this:

```
 # create a new dataframe that has correct mapping
raw_data_map = {'product_number':          ['04', '06', '08', '09', '10'],
                'product_name':            ['Thaai Tea', 'Thaien Tea', 'Maango Tea', 'MangoIs Tea', 'MangoKre Tea'],
                'product_tea_category':    ['Thai Tea', 'Thai Tea', 'Mango Tea', 'Mango Tea', 'Mango Tea']}

# create tea map
tea_map = pd.DataFrame(raw_data_map)
```

And 'remove' the `product number` from your current data:

```
# step one, strip off the first two characters and make a new column
tea_data['product number'] = tea_data['product_name'].str[:3]

# relpace '.' with null 
tea_data['product number'] = tea_data['product number'].str.replace('.', '')
```

Then that will allow you to merge and pull in `tea category`:

```
tea_data.merge(tea_map[['product_number','product_tea_category']] , left_on='product number', right_on='product_number')
```

Which looks like this:
[image: Screen Shot]

Then you can finally run the `groupby`, to get your desired outcome:

```
tea_data.groupby(['product_tea_category']).sum()
```

[image]